# How to transform observed variables to their underlying latent variable in SPSS?

Tags: spss, latent-variable

My questionnaire includes 48 questions (observed variables) that represent 8 different factors (latent variables). All the variables are continuous. I need to compute the latent variables before doing the correlation & regression analyses but the problem is that SPSS doesn't directly create latent variables like SEM softwares.

How can I create latent variables in SPSS?

Comment: How would you like to compute factor scores? Using factor analysis?

Comment: I've already have run the exploratory factor analysis in spss. I checked for factor loading in the "rotated component matrix" after which i reduced the number of my variables to 48 from 52 (deleted 4 variables with low factor loadings). Then I administered the EFA again. By factor scores u mean the results shown in the "Component Score Coefficient Matrix"? Do i need those scores for computing latent variables?

Comment: Factor scores, dear @Cyrus, is another name for values of latent variables. The scores are indeed computed with the help of "Component Score Coefficient Matrix", but the program does the computation for you and saves the scores as new variables in the working data window. Check what is under "Scores" button in Factor analysis dialog box.

Comment: I chose "regression" method in "save as variable" section and it created 8 new variables named FAC_1to8. R these considered to b my 8 latent variables?

Comment: Are you still in doubts?

Comment: I'm afraid yes! For doing the regression analysis i'm gonna need 8 latent variables. I tried the regression with FAC_1toFAC_8 but it gave me no meaningful result! Also the correlation between them were all zero! So what r those FACs for?

Comment: What you've done is Principal component analysis, as I can see. These latents are uncorrelated by definition... I suspect some gross misunderstanding on your side. Perhaps you ought to think it over and, if necessary, post a new question about what you expected and why you didn't get it.

Comment: You'll want to look into the difference between Principal Component Analysis, which is suited to objective data, and Exploratory Factor Analysis, which is suited to observed measures of latent variables.  In SPSS the usual way to conduct the latter is with the Extract...Principal Axis Factoring command.  Then, assuming you rotate the factors, use an oblique  rather than varimax method (I usually use Direct Oblimin) to preserve the (meaningful) correlations among your factors.

Answer (score 2):

The Component score coefficient matrix holds weights of the regression [factor scores](http://pareonline.net/pdf/v14n20.pdf). However, you can save factor scores as new variables in your working SPSS data sheet. See, for example, this Annotated SPSS Output on [Factor Analysis](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/output/factor1.htm) on UCLA server, or this [short tutor](http://psych.unl.edu/psycrs/statpage/pc_score.pdf).