# Calculating factor scores in SPSS

Tags: spss, excel

I have done a factor analysis on different attributes of different cigarette brands (e.g. how expensive consumers find it, etc.).

Three factors were calculated out of the many attributes after reduction.

Now I would like to do a cluster analysis (euclidean distance and Ward method) on factor scores calculated for each person.

THe question is how can I calculate factor scores per person in SPSS or Excel?

Comment: Are you after [How to transform observed variables to their underlying latent variable in SPSS?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/32088/930)

Comment: How can you have factor scores at the level of each person when your factor analysis was performed at the level of brand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the GUI interface for SPSS, it's as simple as re-running the factor analysis, bringing up the "Scores" dialogue box, and selecting the check box "Save as variables".  In the more recent versions of SPSS, there are options for different methods of calculating the respondent level scores; unless you have a really strong reason for choosing another one, I'd accept the default, which is regression.

If you're running SPSS from syntax, then you need to add the following option to your FACTOR command:

/SAVE REG(ALL)

Hope that helps. . .